# Bootstrap modal not working using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a bootstrap modal box and anchor link. When i clicked anchor link it's open modal popup. I have written jquery when link anchor link is clicked to show modal popup. Can any give me suggestion to solve this problem.

**index.html**

```
<div class="update-heading">Email Updates</div>
<div class="email_text">Please confirm which of the FREE email services you would like to receive from us, you can unsubscribe at any time:</div>
<div class="checkbox_list"><input type="checkbox" name="newsletter-daily" value="newsletter-daily" class="ind"><span> </span> <label style="width: 400px;">Compelo Energy Daily Update </label> <a  class="pview" data-toggle="modal" href="#mprof" >preview</a></div>
<div class="checkbox_list"><input type="checkbox" name="newsletter-weekly" value="newsletter-weekly"><span> </span> <label style="width: 400px;">Compelo Energy Weekly Round-up </label><a  class="pview" data-toggle="modal" href="#mprof" >preview</a></div>
```

**Script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".pview").click(function(event){          
            if($(this).parent().find(':checkbox').is(':checked')){
                //alert('parent field is checked'); 
                $('#mprof').modal('show'); 
                console.log('if');
            }else{ 
                //alert('parent field is not hecked'); 
                $('#mprof').modal('hide');
                console.log('else');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: Where is the Bootstrap Modal markup?

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't work, modal is an html construct and you must set it like it needs, so you need html for the modal and change the javascript becuase you are doing an on click on class pview that is not correct....Try this and look the differences....Bye...

```
    <div class="update-heading">Email Updates</div>
    <div class="email_text">Please confirm which of the FREE email services you would like to receive from us, you can unsubscribe at any time:</div>
    <div class="checkbox_list">
        <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter-daily" value="newsletter-daily" class="ind">
        <span> </span> <label style="width: 400px;">Compelo Energy Daily Update </label> 
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox_list">
        <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter-weekly" value="newsletter-weekly">
        <span> </span> <label style="width: 400px;">Compelo Energy Weekly Round-up </label>
    </div>

    <div class="modal bs-example-modal-md fade" id="mprof" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalMprof" >
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header"align="center">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalMprof">Modal</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times; </span>
                <span class="sr-only">Chiudi</span>
            </button>        
          </div>
          <b><div class="modal-body" id="contentModalMprof">
          </div></b>
          <div class="modal-footer">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    $(".checkbox_list").click(function(event){          
        if($(this).parent().find(':checkbox').is(':checked')){
            $('#contentModalMprof').html('preview'); 
            $('#mprof').modal('show'); 
        }else{ 
            $('#mprof').modal('hide');
        }
    });
```

I think there is also another problem because you are doing find checkbox and if is checked modal open but in this way you can have two checkbox checked, maybe it's bettere use radio button or you must do a js to check only one checkbox at time...or when you open the modal reset the checkebox prop checked to false, reset checked...Ciao